# Every time I change the page name formatting is deleted

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I recently purchased a Zonda theme for Magento. I am now trying to rename the URL Key  and Page Title, but when I do change the CMS > Page name the formatting is deleted. This happens even when I switch back to the original name. I then need o re-install the theme. How to I fix this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know what your screenshot is all about, but to change the name and URL key you have to be in the first tab of the CMS Page edition.

Comment: Yes, I know. I wasn't asking how to change CMS page name. I was asking why I my content is altering after I just change the title name and url key. I lose formatting, even if I return title name and urk key back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that your problem is not in page name editing, but in page save. 
Page content is viewed in TinyMCE editor, which can strip HTML tags if they are not listed as allowed tags in it's config. Also it could remove code formatting (tabulations, indents) on save.

Comment: Thanks. How do I change the name without stripping the HTML tags?

Comment: The best way to keep your content from being wrecked by TinyMCE is to disable TinyMCE completely. SYSTEM >> CONFIG >> CONTENT MANAGEMENT >> ENABLED WYSIWYG EDITOR // DISABLE COMPLETELY. TinyMCE is handy for the folks that are terrified when looking at some basic HTML markup, but the markup it generates is typically bad on top of stripping tags it thinks are invalid. If you want, you can disable TinyMCE, change the name/url key, save the page, then re-enable TinyMCE for those that need it.

Comment: Also, to add, I will typically copy/paste the page/block contents from Magento admin into a proper code editor where I can make my changes and copy/paste back into the admin text area. Doing this allows you to have fundamental code editing features like undo and tabs, and if you save the page contents and they get totally wrecked, you have the original code to replace it with (especially handy since there is no versioning in CMS pages/blocks).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch:)